# shader: weird stripe

Tags: shaders

Why this is happening!?

[image]

[image]

osl script:

```
shader TestNoise(
    vector vec = (0,0,0),

    output vector outV = (0,0,0)
){
    outV = (vec[0],vec[1],vec[2]);

}
```

In this case, it should not modify anything. It just passing the same value. Why is this happening?

I mean, if the public input vec is receiving the texture coordinate object vec = (x,y,z) and the outV = (vec[0],vec[ 1 ],vec[ 2 ]) is should vec = outV = (x,y,z) = (vec[ 0 ],vec[ 1 ],vec[ 2 ]), right?
In this image, instead of a black and white stripe is should not be a default checker?
I don't know, can someone explain to me?

Comment: Why is what happening? You didn't tell us what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a mismatch in types in the assignment of the output variable - you need to include the 'vector' type in the assignment.

ie, instead of :

```
outV = (vec[0],vec[1],vec[2]);
```

Change it to :

```
outV = vector(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2]);
```

So the final script should be :

```
shader TestNoise(
    vector vec = (0,0,0),

    output vector outV = (0,0,0)
){
    outV = vector(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2]);

}
```

Comment: why does this happen?

Comment: Without the ‘vector’ keyword you’re not casting it to a vector - it’s just a list of values - and it seems that it’s effectively just passing the last one (Z) back from the shader as a scalar. This means that your Texture is only being plotted in one dimension - so stripes in the Z direction. Technically I suppose it should be flagged as a syntax error at compile time but since vectors can be set to a scalar (so setting to 0.5 sets it to vector(0.5,0.5,0.5)) it compiles as falid but is actually discarding vec[0] and vec[1].